# How to interpret Quasipoisson glm p values given hidden default categories?

Tags: r

[Hi
I am struggling with how to interpret my Quasipoisson glm table due to what i have learned to be default categories for example in my case i have 3 sites but there are only 2 sites shown in the table (Husab Mine and Swakop), the third site (Hope Mine is not shown), and for sex is only male (M) displayed and female is a default category.
I am studying pollinator visitation rate to a dioecious plant, comparing visits to male plants (M) and visits to female plants (F) within and across sites. All i want to find out is if pollinator visitation rate is affected by site and plant sex.
My data are overdispersed thus opted to use the Quasipoisson robust model, which i now find confusing to interpret.
So, i assume the model is comparing the two sites in the table to the default site i.e. Husab Mine vs Hope Mine, and Swakop vs Hope Mine, but is it also not supposed to compare between the the two sites in the table i.e. Husab Mine vs Swakop? Which p values should i pick to conclude if visitation rate is significantly affected by site and sex?
Thank for your help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxIIc.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I got the solution from (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674148/one-p-value-for-glm-model). I wanted to have 3 single p-values, one for sex, one for site and one for interaction between sex and site. I ran anova(glm.Q3, test = "F") which gave me the table so now it is easy to interpret. All the 3 p-values are significant so i can conclude that visitation rate is affected by site, sex and there is a significant effect. Unless if it is wrong to conclude so?